# Ideal Superconductor connected to Zero Voltage

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, superconductivity

If an ideal superconductor was just left alone, with no potential difference, what would be the current flowing in it?

According to Ohm's Law, $V = IR$

Hence, if a superconductor of $0\Omega$ resistance was just placed with $0V$ across its ends, substituting these values into Ohm's Law, we get $0 = I0$.

In this condition what current would flow through the superconductor; would it be infinite or zero?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62664/

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86677/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80400/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Ohm’s law is vacuously true for a superconductor, regardless of the current going through it. You cannot use it to determine the current

You have to provide the current through some other means, like a current source, or putting it in series with a resistive circuit. Then whatever amount of current (up to the critical current) will conduct with no voltage.